# Animated random number not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the code like post in 
[Random Number Effect In Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363916/random-number-effect-in-jquery/15562546#15562546)..
and the result http://jsfiddle.net/ZDsMa/94/...

Now I write full code html and jquery in one file php(`index.php`) and place on my server...

```
<html>
<title>Randomize Number</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#output {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 80px;
    width: 160px;
    color: red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
var output, started, duration, desired;
// Constants
duration = 5000;
desired = '50';

// Initial setup
output = $('#output');
started = new Date().getTime();

// Animate!
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // If the value is what we want, stop animating
    // or if the duration has been exceeded, stop animating
    if (output.text().trim() === desired || new Date().getTime() - started > duration) {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );

    } else {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );
    }
}, 1000);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output">-</div>                    
</body>
</html>
```

The animated random number not displaying (jscript not running, only box with '-' characher/css)

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure your code gets executed after the page is rendered. Try wrapping it with:

```
...
<script>
$( function () {
    var output, started, duration, desired;
    // Constants
    duration = 5000;

    ...

    }, 1000);
});
</script>
...
```

You can find more info here [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code that interacts with the DOM in a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
})
```

Comment: i do not understand Blender, where should i place the code "$(document).ready()" above..??

Comment: @andry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function

Answer (score 0):

hi use this javascript code it work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var output, started, duration, desired;
// Constants
duration = 5000;
desired = '50';

// Initial setup
output = $('#output');
started = new Date().getTime();

// Animate!
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // If the value is what we want, stop animating
    // or if the duration has been exceeded, stop animating
    if (output.text().trim() === desired || new Date().getTime() - started > duration) {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );

    } else {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );
    }
}, 1000);
})
```